# Is my ssh key correct? It doesn't start with 'ssh-rsa' (Trying to set up private key validation, worried about being locked out of server)

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I am trying to set up private key validation on my server. I think this is a simple question, I just don't want to get locked out of the server by mistake. I generated an ssh key with ssh-keygen, it just looks different from the tutorial I am watching on deployment. It is just a long list of characters as such :

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAA..etc
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, the video I am watching on deployment shows an ssh key like such:

```
ssh-rsa b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAA..etc USER@desktop2FBF
```

I am not sure if they look different because I am on a mac and the guide is using windows. But my key does not begin with `ssh-rsa` or end with `USER@`... Also, I see there are two files created with this command, the .pub one I cannot open, so I assume I am copying and pasting the key from the right file(the only one I can open).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key that begins with `ssh-rsa` is the **public** key.

The first one in the question is your **private** key.

The public key is the one that should be transferred to the server.  It will end up in the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: I am assuming that is the .pub file. However, when I click this file it says I do not have an application that can open it? Shoud I just open it via the command line with nano?

Comment: It is a text file. You can open it with any text editor.

Comment: Sorry, just had to click 'choose application'. Don't know why it didn't open in a default text-editor window, but anyway, thanks! Almost tried to use the wrong key...

Comment: Ill accept answer when I can